# Where's the actual Remote-SSH source code repo on github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm looking for the source to the VSCode-Insider's Remote SSH extension, and everything seems to point to  to [Microsoft/vscode-remote-release](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release), which has no code, just issues and Markdown docs. Anyone know where the actual extension source is? I'm curious of the inner workings. I've also checked on [microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) and don't see it either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That was asked in [`Microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 30](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/30)

It refers to [this FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_why-arent-the-remote-development-extensions-or-their-components-open-source):

> ### Why aren't the Remote Development extensions or their components open source?
>
> The Visual Studio Code Remote Development extensions and their related components will use an [open planning, issue, and feature request process](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/feedback), but are not currently open-source.
> As with other service-based extensions such as [Visual Studio LiveShare](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack) and [IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode), we have made the decision to keep them closed source.

---

As [Haaleo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6925187/haaleo) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979489/wheres-the-actual-remote-ssh-source-code-repo-on-github/55979526?noredirect=1#comment98617798_55979526):

> You can check the extension's installed source code.
> Under windows navigate to `%USERPROFILE%/.vscode-insiders/extensions`

Comment: @HaaLeo Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I had an issue because this extension requires TCP forwarding which is completely blocked because of security policy and I thought ok easy I can just add this feature without using TCP redirect but with custom shell. VSCode is done for me this is completely sneaked into and M$ intentions are clear. Good luck with their choice with their next visualstudio,